# MariaDB Full Text Index - How to query old data as well

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, full-text-search

I have added new full text index to mariadb

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table name> ADD FULLTEXT INDEX records
```

I can query against this index only newly added and updated records but for older records (which is added before this index) I cannot query

Is there any workaround that I can also fetch older records

Comment: Give an example.  Adding the index should index the entire table.  Also provide version number and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally it would be build, when you added the index

But you can [OTIMIZE TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimize-table/) yourtablename

> The fulltext index is only fully re-organized when an OPTIMIZE TABLE statement is run.